# mute errors generated by bash itself

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I need to have an arrangement wherein sometimes `bash -ic` is executed without pty. I have to use -i (.bashrc run is required) and I have to not have pty (stdin transmission via ssh). However, I do not want to see this:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (20605): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

I could only filter out that with `2> >(grep -v 'bash: ')`, but I would prefer to muffle bash itself because that filter also applies to whatever command (-c) is run by that bash.

To re-iterate I am looking for a way to silence warnings related to bash itself - not script it executes.

If you'd like to reproduce it, try this:

```
$ echo hello |ssh -t you@<linuxHost> bash -ic cat -
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
hello
```

Comment: Have you considered `ssh -t`? Besides, this question is probably best suited for https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @xhienne, I am using `ssh -t` as you can see in my question. Besides, bash programming is quite popular at https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: What is bash doing for you here?  I would execute your example as `ssh -f hostname 'cmd'`.

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden, like i said, I rely on sourcing .bashrc. That's a prerequisite for remote commands.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh -tt`.

Quoting the [`ssh` manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html):

> `-t` Force pseudo-terminal allocation. This can be used to execute
> arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
> very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services. **Multiple `-t`
> options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.**

Comment: Unfortunately. It breaks scripts fed from files. So I’d insist that the question was about muffling bash.

Comment: Would you mind telling me how adding a terminal breaks things? Fixing this might just be a matter of adding another option to ssh.

Comment: I am not sure why you so adamant to discuss a question I didn't ask, but to appease your curiosity, try `ssh -tt <host> bash -is <test` with `-tt` and `-t`, where `test` is any script you like, and taste the difference.

Comment: I didn't ask you for the difference, I asked you how it breaks things. And if I'm so adamant, this is because your question displays all the symptoms of an XY problem. For example, if you are not interested in an interactive session and only use the -i flag so that Bash reads your .bashrc, then don't use -i and source your bashrc file. Of course, like in any XY problem, you will tell me that you absolutely need that -i option, so just take this as an example, not as a solution to your problem. Anyway I still think you would have better answers on unix.stackexchange.com